# This function looks quasiconvex, can't understand why

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convexity, convex-optimization

Suppose that $\mathbf{C}$ is a given matrix with non-negative entries in $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $d$ is a given scalar, and let $g(\mathbf{y})$ be defined by $$g(\mathbf{y}):=\max_{\mathbf{x}\in\Omega }\sum_i\sqrt{x_i} $$ where $\Omega$ is the set of all $\mathbf{x}$ satisfying $$\sum_i x_i\min_j\{c_{ij}-y_j\} \leq d \\ \sum_i x_i \leq 1 . $$

For some reason, numerical simulations suggest that $g(\mathbf{y})$ is quasiconvex (but not convex).  Does anyone have any recommendations how I might prove this (if it's actually true at all)?  Are there any "nice" properties that $g(\mathbf{y})$ has that I might be missing?  My ultimate goal is to minimize $g(\mathbf{y})$ over a certain domain, so any advice towards this end would be appreciated.

Comment: you probably want to add $x$ with positive entries in the definition of $\Omega$, otherwise the sum of $\sqrt{x_i}$ is not defined for some $x$ in $\Omega$.

Comment: Well, in convex optimization, one often assumes an extended-valued interpretation of the square root; i.e., $\sqrt{x}=-\infty$ if $x<0$. Under that interpretation, there is an implicit constraint that the $x_i$s are nonnegative, and there is no need to add it.